# Django: Getting models with apps.get_model on models.py

Tags: python, django

On circular import of Django Is their any way i can grab a model object with `myModel = apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')` inside models.py file ?

I know i can use `models.ForeignKey('app.model',....)`

But in my case i am making a query in the models.py for custom function. So that i need to grab the model object. Also can't import it in normal way as already imported this file class in the other file. So must be a circular import.

This code `myModel = apps.get_model('app_name', 'model_name')` works fine on views.py but in models.py doesn't. Since according to django the all models.py get called after settings.py and after that views and others. so while trying to use `get_model` inside models.py getting this error

> File "/home/mypc/.virtualenvs/VSkillza/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 132, in check_models_ready
>       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
>   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Alasdair that works. Tnx for you suggestion. You answer deserve to mark as complete :)
Let's do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can break the circular import by moving the import inside the custom function. That way, the model is loaded when the function runs, not when the module is loaded.

```
def my_function():
    from myapp.models import MyModel
```

The circular import suggests that your code is structured incorrectly, but we can't give you any suggestions since you haven't shown it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
     import importlib

     mymodels = importlib.import_module("app.models")
     mymodels.YourModel
     #query
     mymodels.YourModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: HI @ocobacho that's a great solution as well. Though  first answer already solved my issue.  Tnx for commenting :)